# Reading an Input File and Getting no output from code

Tags: java, loops, file-io

I am assigned to write to another document using data from an input file, and calculating the mean and standard deviation from that file. I have an issue where my code is compiling correctly (according to Dr.Java) but is not giving an output to the output file. I have the code attached that I think is the problem area. It may either be the loops used or reading the file before the loops. Could anyone tell me if those places are the places of error?

```
    // Create a File object passing it the filename
  File readFile = new File(filename);
  // Create a Scanner object passing File object
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(filename);
  // Perform a priming read to read the first line of the file;
  line = inputFile.nextLine();
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) //create a loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
    {   
     while( Double.parseDouble(line) != -1)
      {
         sum += Double.parseDouble(line); //convert the line into a double value and add the value to the sum
         count++; //increment the counter
         line = inputFile.nextLine(); //read a new line from the file
      }
         mean = sum/count;
    }
    inputFile.close();
```

The output file code:

```
    // Create a FileWriter object using "OutputFileProcess.txt"
    File file = new File("OutputFileProcess.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
  // Create a PrintWriter object passing the FileWriter object
      PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("OutputFileProcess.txt");
  // Print the results to the output file
      outputFile.println(mean);
      outputFile.println(stdDev);
  // Close the output file
      outputFile.close();
```

The code needs two loops, one to continue until the ned, and one to exclude any negative numbers in the text file. I should also introduce myself. I am Joe.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger

Comment: So where are you writing to the output file? The code that you posted is for reading.

Comment: I just added the output file code. I didn't want to post too much of my code because I think the error is in one area only.

Comment: What does the input file look like? Does it really use -1 as a sentinel?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the core of your problem, but one of your while loops is obsolete.

If the inner condition

```
Double.parseDouble(line) != -1
```

becomes false, the outer while loop will not change the value of `line` and the inner while loop will never be entered anymore.
So at the moment the whole algorithm stops at the first -1.

A better way to write this down would be

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    final String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    final double lineAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(line);
    if (lineAsDouble  != -1D) {
        sum += lineAsDouble;
        count++;
    }
}
final double mean = (double) sum / (double) count;
```

You should also consider parsing and comparing the values as Integers (if they all are), since comparing doubles with == is always dangerous.